# JavaScript change color of div "array" on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, colors

I want to create a questionaire where users have a certain number of points that they can allocate to different categories. The allotment is different depending on the user.
Assigning the points should be realized in the following way:

1. The number of points are displayed as an array of boxes (either floating divs or table tds. What's better?). Unspent points are shown in orange, spent points are shown in lime/green.
2. The user can click on any orange box to indicate how many points he wants to allocate next. All orange boxes from the left up to (and including) the clicked box are highlighted in yellow. The number of highlighted boxes is stored in a hidden form field.
3. The user now clicks the category/element he wants to allocate the points to. By clicking the element the name of the element, the number from (2) and other form stuff are send via AJAX to a script handling database stuff. The highlightes yellow boxes are now turned green and the counter is updated.

Example:

[image: example]

I can handle the AJAX stuff, however I have no clue how to handle the select/highlight "mechanic". My basic thought is: have a variable `points_spent` that starts at 0 and is increased every time points are spent (duh). The boxes are divs that have different CSS classes (box_spent, box_highlight, box_avaibale) that handle the color.

One JavaScript is checking the value for points_spent and will change the class of the divs with the id `box_1` to `box_n` to `box_spent`.

A second JavaScript is triggered by clicking on a box. It checks if the click is valid (i.e. on an orange or yellow box) and lighlights the boxes accordingly...

But how do I do this with JS? I would have no problem doing this with PHP, but that would be horrible for the users to wait after every click :/

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$('.box_highlight,.box_available').click(function(e) {
   $clicked = $(e.target);

   // Highlight box that was just clicked
   $clicked.addClass('box_highlight').removeClass('box_available');

   // Find all elements to the left that aren't already spent and highlight them.
   $clicked.prevAll('.box_available').addClass('box_highlight').removeClass('box_available');

   // Remove highlight of any boxes to the right
   $clicked.nextAll('.box_highlight').removeClass('box_highlight').addClass('box_available');
});

$('.category').click(function(e){

   // The container of the clicked category
   $categoryEl = $(e.target);

   // Determine which category was clicked.
   var category = $categoryEl.html();
   var points = currentPointValue();
   var highlighted = $('#box_container').find('.box_highlight');

   $.post({
      /* Your ajax options go here */
      data: {
         category: category,
         points: points
      },
      success: function() {
          $categoryEl.append(points);
          $highlighted.removeClass('box_highlight').addClass('box_spent');
      }
   });
});

var $boxContainer = $('#box_container');

function currentPointValue() {
   $boxContainer.find('.box_highlight').length;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'm fairly new to JS, having mostly worked with PHP before. I'll play around with your example and try to modify it a bit and will post how it went :)

Comment: Ok, i might have a very basic question: I tried a bare-bones version of your script that shold just return the id of the clicked box. Using $('.box_available .box_highlight').click(function() does NOT work, however just using ONE class name does. Why is that? Am I missing some important prequisite?

Comment: My mistake, I omitted the comma between the selectors. I've updated the answer to reflect the correct selector.